# Where can I find documents on the 1992 fight between French soldiers and Somalian fighters?

Tags: military, france, africa

I read in this French blog that before the battle of Mogadishu in 1993, French soldiers did fight successfully and manage to achieve their mission in June 1992 during the Oryx Operation (They were sent to help Pakistani troops that were ambushed).

I've never read anything about this event, and sometimes french military history tends to consider everything as a victory. Is there articles or books on this particular event ?

The link of the blog article  can be found [here](http://lavoiedelepee.blogspot.se/2013/10/mogadiscio-1993-loryx-et-le-faucon-noir.html). It is written in French language.

It explains approximately what was the main differences between the French and the American way of doing things and compare those two battles.

- The French CO (Commanding officer) was on the field whereas the American CO was at the CP monitoring the situation with video-camera
- French troops tend to avoid heavy supporting fire in the middle of civil area and therefore they are able to save their ammo much longer.
- American soldier stayed in the streets, the most dangerous place in urban combat

Comment: [This news story from 1992](http://articles.latimes.com/1992-12-19/news/mn-2122_1_french-foreign-legion) shows a less chauvinistic approach, or maybe a different flavor of chauvinism

Comment: It was not the Legion that fight there, but the " troupes de marines", the former colonial army. And there were people from several regiments fighting this day. ( When you speak about the unit in Calvi, it's the 2nd airborne regiment of the French Foreign Legion. They are very proud of their specificity.... )

Comment: That's because the first regiment got whacked in Dien Bien Phu.  I met the 2d regiment shortly after the'd come back from Chad.

Comment: The first regiment survived Dien Bien Phu, but was dissolved by the french government in 1961 after the attempted military coup in Alger. ( It was the only unit that supported the rebel generals, and they were punished for it.)

Answer (score -1):

You would have to contact the appropriate units in the French Army, travel to France, and obtain the unit history. The information you will find on the internet about obscure engagements will be very limited.

My understanding is that the operation was small and brief, and it was totally different from the Americans, who were stuck in the middle of Mogadishu.